# how to do a join in JPQL?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I need help getting started with a JPQL query,

I have a Program that has many Sessions and each Session has an Instructor.

Given an Instructor, I need a query that returns the list of Programs that have a Session that is taught by that instructor.

I know how to do something like:

```
Select p from Program as p where p.id = :programId
```

or

```
Select s from Session as s where s.instructor.id = :instructorId
```

But how do I join these two queries together/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on your mapping.  If a program truly "has" many sessions, meaning that the program entity has a collection of sessions, and each session "has" a single instructor, then you can do something like

```
select p from Program p join p.sessions s where s.instructor.id = :instructorId
```